# Recognize PHP errors in Actionscript 3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I'm connecting to some PHP files in Actionscript 3 (Adobe Flex).
But when one of the PHP files has an error, my Flash project doesn't work properly anymore.

Is there a possibility to detect a PHP error in Actionscript, so that I could show a message with Actionscript that something went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem actually causes a call to throw an error I believe you'll receive a FaultEvent in AS3 instead of a ResultEvent and can add a listener for it.  If it's not the case that it throws an error but rather it just bombs out you could put some text into the response that indicates it completed successfully.  If you have XML being returned as the result you can include a node at the end of processing that says something like "processingCompletedSuccess"  and look for this node in the result handler in Flex, or similarly if it's a flat text result you could append a "success" as the last word then read the last line in the result handler and see if it indicates success (stripping it out for further processing).

Comment: Pretty sure a FaultEvent does not get thrown if the php has an error. Since the PHP server is giving a response and not failure.

Comment: Yah if it returns 200 OK you're probably right this was actually a point I've been waning back and forth about whether or not it was true.  If there is an uncaught exception in PHP will it always still return 200 OK or are there scenarios where the module and server are properly configured but the execution of PHP results in a non 200 OK response?  I'll try to do more testing on that one before suggesting it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the error is.  If is a fatal, non catchable error, then no.  However, most erros will likely be catchable, and therefore be able to be handled by responding with an appropriate error.

Look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what type of data you are returning from the "PHP file" so I will ASSume it is XML.

When I work with XML I stanardize my XML to follow a very specific light format.

```
<root>
  <data>
     // your data here
  </data>
  <error/>
  <message/>
</root>
```

And in my php I wrap it in a try catch. In the catch block I will return the error inside the message node. And will assign a 1 inside the error node.
So an error messge might look like this.

```
<root>
  <data/>
  <error>1</error>
  <message>some error from php here</messge>
</root>
```

So on the AS side all i need to do is test for

```
response.error == 1
```

psudo code but you should get the idea.